# Changing symbol color in R kaplan meier plot?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Possibly a foolish question, but how would one change the symbol aka mark colors in a kaplan meier plot? I know the lines.survfit has an option to change the actual mark symbol, but apparently not the color of the symbol (only the color of the line)

I tried to manually add the marks using line() or points() and change the color and symbol of those marks using pch and col. However the marks were incomplete; not all of the censored events had a mark using that method.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Cannot figure out what the problem might be ... seems to work as expected:

```
 #Example from help page ("works")

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status==2) ~ sex, pbc,subset=1:312)
 plot(fit, mark.time=FALSE, xscale=365.25,
         xlab='Years', ylab='Survival')
 lines(fit[1], lwd=2, col="black", xscale=365.24)    
 points(fit[1], lwd=2, col="red", xscale=365.24)
```

Need a counter-example .... with data and code.

Comment: Hmmm runnign that will make the line red and the symbol border red. What I'm trying to do however is to make the symbol a solid red and the line stay another color, lets say black. Edit: Never mind, your solution works, I accidentally ran a different line. Thank you so much!

Comment: If that is not your desire the fix would seem glaringly obvious. Change the color arguments.